# ActiveAdmin custom filter . Order Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, filter, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a little problem regarding a filter.

```
 #filter :admin_user, :as => :select, :collection => proc{[AdminUser.exec_backoffice,AdminUser.exec_hotline,AdminUser.exec_customer_relations].order('name asc')}
```

How can i fix this filter so it can order all the Admin Users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No point in putting different groups (scopes) into an array and then sort it - just operate on `AdminUser`:

```
filter :admin_user,
  as: :select,
  collection: -> AdminUser.order('name asc').pluck(:name)
```

If, though, you only need to have specific groups/scopes of `AdminUser` (not all of them), create a new scope:

```
scope :for_filtering, -> { 
  exec_backoffice
    .merge(exec_hotline)
    .merge(exec_customer_relations)
}
```

And then use it:

```
filter :admin_user,
  as: :select,
  collection: -> AdminUser.for_filtering.order('name asc').pluck(:name)
```